# errors with compile without .NET Native compile in release mode

Tags: c#, .net, json, xamarin

I use Xamarin.Forms. I use file data.json embedded as resource. In Debug in work, but in release with  .NET Native compile it crash with some errors.

I was advised to use this https://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html and change RD.XML file. What should I put in there to get rid of my mistakes? My errors

```
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException" in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
"System.IO.FileNotFoundException" in System.Private.Reflection.Core.dll
"System.AggregateException" in System.Private.Threading.dll
"Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException" in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
"System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
"System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" in System.Linq.Expressions.dll
"System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
"System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
"System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException"  Newtonsoft.Json.dll
"System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException" in project.UWP.McgInterop.dll
"System.Reflection.MissingMetadataException"  project.UWP.McgInterop.dll
```

My code

```
        var assembly = typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly; 

        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("project.data.json");

        string text = "";
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream))
        {
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Levels = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Level>>(text, new MyConverter());
```

Comment: if you embed the file in your project as a Content type file you can read it using normal file I/O and avoid using reflection

Comment: Could you please give an example of this or a link where to read more? I did not hear about it. In xamarin.forms pcl as far as I know you can not use system.io

Comment: in Forms you would need to use DI and do the actual file I/O from your platform project

Comment: Did you find any way how to fix it?